# Why use #' with lambda?

Tags: lambda, lisp, quote

Why should I use #' together with lambda? It is usually written that way, so I guess it is good form. But these lines seem equal to me:

```
> (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3))
(2 3 4)
> (mapcar (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3))
(2 3 4)
```

Anyone care to enlighten a beginner about the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#'` is shorthand for `function`, which returns a pointer to a function (instead of applying it).  `lambda` returns a function, and it's usual to want a pointer to that function.  Since this is so common, there is also a macro (in variable space) that does it for you, which is called `lambda` as well.  Both lines of code are identical.

Which is better comes down to the [Lisp-1/Lisp-2 debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace): in Common Lisp you can do either, thanks to the macro.  As always, be consistent.

Answer (score 14):

It is different in various Lisp dialects. The following uses Common Lisp:

First  **#'  is a short notation for (function ...)**. So the following are only textually different, but Common Lisp reads them as the same:

```
#'(lambda (x) (* x 2))
```

and

```
(function (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

#' is a readmacro, and transforms when Lisp code is read by the Lisp system.

If Lisp evaluates

```
(function (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

the **Lisp system creates an function object and FUNCTION returns it as its value**.

So, whenever you need a function as a value, then you need to write it like that. A function as a value is needed, when you want to pass it to another functions as an argument, when you want to return it from a function or when you want to store it in a variable. Examples:

```
(map #'(lambda (x) (* x 2)) '(1 2 3))

(defun (y) #'(lambda (x) (* x y)))

(defparameter *twice-fn* #'(lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

Now, what is  (lambda (x) (* x 2)) ?

It is two different things depending on context.

**Lambda expression**

The lambda expression can be used instead of a function name:

```
(function foo)   and    (function (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

and

```
(foo 17)    and  ((lambda (x) (* x 2)) 17)
```

Above two are legal Common Lisp syntax. There a lambda expression can be used directly.

Note that the following two forms are **illegal** in Common Lisp:

```
(#'(lambda (x) (* x 2)) 17)   ; illegal in Common Lisp

(function #'(lambda (x) (* x 2)))  ; illegal in Common Lisp
```

**Macro**

During the Common Lisp standardization process a macro LAMBDA has been added (it was not part of the first description, CLtL1, of Common Lisp). It makes it possible to write slightly shorter code. Example:

```
(lambda (x) (* x 2))
```

In above case LAMBDA is a macro. During macro expansion it will be expanded to:

```
(function (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

Remember that in above FUNCTION form, the inner lambda is part of a lambda expression, denotes the function and will not be expanded.

So, now the three examples from above can be written as:

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) '(1 2 3))

(defun (y) (lambda (x) (* x y)))

(defparameter *twice-fn* (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
```

It is slightly shorter, looks a little bit less cluttered and looks slightly more similar to Scheme code. It is just looking a bit better for programmers used to read and write Scheme code.

**Summary**

a)  (function (lambda (x) (* x 2)))   is the 'true' way to write code that returns a function as a value.

b)  #'(lambda (x) (* x 2))  is a shorter notation of above

c)  (lambda (x) (* x 2))   is even shorter, but uses macro expansion to create the form of a).